# Can not install php 5.5 opcache on Centos 6.4

Tags: php, yum, centos6, opcache

I have php 5.5 installed on CentOS (from Remi repo, as far as I remember).

Now I wanted to turn on opcache and configure it, but it turned out that I have no opcache.so file in the system. So I tried to install it with yum.

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-zendopcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.proserve.nl
* epel: mirror.proserve.nl
* extras: ftp.tudelft.nl
* remi: remi.mirrors.hostinginnederland.nl
* rpmforge: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
* updates: mirror.proserve.nl
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-zendopcache.x86_64 0:7.0.2-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Installed: php-common-5.5.5-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php(api) = 20121113-64
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
       Installed: php-common-5.5.5-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to cope with this problem, if I have newer versions of php installed and dependencies can not be properly resolved?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Oh, I've already got answer to my question :) Add it here, maybe, someone else will use it.

Initially I installed php using such command

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

Now I just ADDED missing extension with this command

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-opcache
```

And it worked!!! phpinfo() shows needed module :)

Comment: Can't get it to work. Got centOs 6 and remi php 5.6 installed. php -v outputs opcache. but iam unable to access my httpdocs files. connection just quits, no error in apache log. after yum remove php-opcache, everything works again. am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks buddy! Worked for me

Comment: I had the same problem as @fubbe.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when installing php-mcrypt and I used this command:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php-mcrypt
```